# How can I put currency icon in front of the value of TextInput in ReactNative?

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, stylesheet, textinput

I need to put the currency icon in front of the value when the user is putting an amount, but it is not so easy. I spent all day, but still not found the ideal solution. My best way was to wrap child component to TextInput,like this:

```
          <TextInput
            style={SS.input}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent' editable={!props.disabled}
            keyboardType={keyboardType} autoCapitalize='none'
            autoCorrect={false} selection={state.position}
            value={state.value} onChangeText={this._onChangeText}
            onFocus={this._onFocus} onBlur={this._onBlur}
            autoFocus={autoFocus}>
            {!!this.props.icon && !!state.value && (
              <Text style={{marginLeft: 10}}>{this.props.icon}</Text>
            )}
          </TextInput>
```

But this decision has a few minus. The first one it is not possible to style child component, I can not set left padding from the amount. And the second it is the focus of TextInput go after the icon. Can somebody help me please.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found the best solution, you need to do this way, set the style of the TextInput so that it becomes invisible. And to display the input, add Text component at the top with the same parameters, so that it is displayed exactly at the top of the native one. It's like a mask.

```
<View style={container}>
 <TextInput
            style={[SS.input, styles.input]}
            placeholder={props.placeholder}
            value={state.value} onChangeText={this._onChangeText}
            onFocus={this._onFocus} onBlur={this._onBlur}
            // make invisible text
            color={'rgba(0,0,0,0)'} 
            autoFocus={autoFocus} />
          // render currency symbol with value that depends on the props
          {!!props.maskedTextColor !! && props.currencySymbol && !!state.value && (
            <Text
              color={props.maskedTextColor}
              textStyle={'menuSliders'}
              style={styles.maskedText}>
              {`${state.value} ${props.currencySymbol}`}
            </Text>
          )}
<View/>
```

And you need to put Text component exactly the same like  component, and put style, in my case it was:

```
    maskedText: {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: 15,
    },
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe what you're looking for is the CSS `::after` pseudoelement.
Here is an example using a `contenteditable` span:

```css
#money {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}

#money::after {
  content: " €";
}
```

```html
<span id="money" contenteditable="true"></span>
```

Comment: no Andre, it is not what i need, there is no span in React Native

Comment: i tried " €" this way, but in this case it is not possible to delete the input value